# how to display tool tip in different directions(in java swing)

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

In my application, which contains a label, I want to display tooltips when I mouse over the label. My requirement is to display the tooltips in different directions.
ex:- see this image

[image]

[image]

Comment: The location of the tool-tip is usually set according to where it would *naturally* appear, barring there being too little space to display it in the default location, *then* it might be shown to the left or above the component.  Why such an unusual and counter-intuitive set of tool-tips?  What is supposed to happen to the (for e.g.) right hand tool-tip if there is not enough screen space to the right of the component to display it?

Comment: ToolTip is something, components from pre_dinosaurus edges, you have to layout (overlay) multiple JLabel or to use JLayer (Java7), painting an illusion, usage of JLayer is very simple and quite easy

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a custom class that extends JLabel and implements MouseMotionListener.
Take a look at this tutorial and you'll see what I mean:

[How to Write a Mouse-motion Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html)

You'll have to experiment with this to get the customization that you want, but I believe this will work for you and should be fairly easy.